# Windows Phone 8.1 Http Get Background Task returns null

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, async-await, task, dotnet-httpclient

I'm working on some basic windows phone 8 app where I have some background task to perform.
I use the HttpClient library for my request.
Here is my code:

```
private static async Task<string> getSessionToken()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(MY_URL_HERE);

        string statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();

        return statusCode;
    }
```

Now I call this method in the MainPage() method :

```
       public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        tokenTxt.Text = getSessionToken().Result;

    }
```

The tokenTxt is an instance of the the TextBlock. Here is my MainPage.xaml file:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock 
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        FontSize="30"
        Name="tokenTxt"> 
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Now when I run this program, I keep on having null being returned in the getSessionToken().Result

What am I doing wrong here ???

Comment: I'm using the windows phone 8 emulator and this is the exception I get :                                                                                                                    Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Net.Http.Phone.ni.DLL

Comment: What is the exception message and stack trace?

Comment: Are you sure StatusCode is really what you want there? That's just the HTTP status code; e.g. 200, 404, etc.

Comment: @svick the exception is : System.InvalidOperationException in System.Net.Http.Phone.ni.DLL

Comment: @sellotape I just want to see a response: be it the status code or the actual  message itself sent back by the server: like I said the problem itself is with this line: getSession().Result which raises the exception.

Comment: Nothing looks particularly incorrect. If you try just assign a constant text value e.g. "Test" to tokenTxt.Text instead, does it succeed?

Comment: @ClaudeHangui That's not the exception message or the stack trace. Can you post those?

Comment: @svick this is the exception message I have: An exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code. When I clicked on view detail I got this: Count = error CS0103: The name 'InnerExceptionCount' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @sellotape YES initializing (with "helloworld" say...) the variable tokenTxT was alright when I launched the app. the string value was visible in the output

Comment: I think you need to submit an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we use to replicate the issue.